# Checkout page error required fields

Tags: php, magento2.2, onepage-checkout

I use google maps autocomplete to fill address[0] field and city field and autocomplete these fields from jquery after getting response from map. After the fields populated I press place order but error occures that

```
address field is required, city field is required.
```

What's the problem some one tell me how to prevent this or how to disable required from these fields...

Comment: Not sure if the same issue, but I've noticed that if I have auto-fill extensions enabled in my browser (in this case LastPass) the details entered in the first half of the checkout sometimes get cleared if I use the auto-fill on the second half of the checkout, hence why I would get the empty fields errors.

Comment: You have any idea how to disable require.